# Why won't console commands work in CoD 4?

Tags: cheats, call-of-duty-4-modern-warfare

I want to create a new movie cfg. When I am in multiplayer and load a new devmap with:

```
/devmap mp_mapname
```

I can't get other commands to work. Every time I insert a new command in the console and hit enter, it appears to be a new text-chat message.

Can anyone help me with this one?